# How to automatic fill textbox depend upon select option from drop down

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have created one IMS System. In that i have to create bill on order page and in order page when i select customer name from drop down than customer_address,customer_phone and gst number should automatically fill in text box.In database i have created one table named partys in that all data are available(Customer_name,Customer_address,customer_phone and gst) If anybody knows solution than please help. Below is my code

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gross_amount" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style="text-align:left;">Customer Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <select name="customer_name" id="client" style="width:100%;">
                    <?php
                      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'stock')
                        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
                      $query = "SELECT * FROM partys";
                      $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['party_name'] ?>"><?php echo $row['party_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gross_amount" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style="text-align:left;">Customer Address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_address" name="customer_address" placeholder="Enter Customer Address" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gross_amount" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style="text-align:left;">Customer Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_phone" name="customer_phone" placeholder="Enter Customer Phone" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gstin" class="col-sm-5 control-label" style="text-align:left;">GSTIN</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gstin" name="gstin" placeholder="Enter GST Number" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // On change of the dropdown do the ajax
        $("#client").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    // Change the link to the file you are using
                    url: '/create.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    // This just sends the value of the dropdown
                     data: {customer_name : party_name},
                     dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Parse the jSON that is returned
                        // Using conditions here would probably apply
                        // incase nothing is returned
                        var response    =   JSON.parse(response);
                        // These are the inputs that will populate
                        $("#customer_address").val(response.customer_address);
                        $("#customer_phone").val(response.customer_phone);
                        $("#gstin").val(response.gstin);
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: May I know exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I am not getting data in textbox when i am selecting option from dropdown

Comment: please check if you are getting any data through ajax.

write alert(response); after function(response){

Comment: i have updated my code please go through it and i have tried alert(response) but it is not generating an alert message

Comment: I am telling that let you test that whether create.php is sending any data or not and to test that you need to write alert(response); and run script if any popup box will appear then create.hp is returning data otherwise it is not

Comment: create.php is the same file in which i have written all this code.

Comment: no you have to create another file in which there will be  code to fetch data from db and echo it. and give that file name in url instead of create.php. use datatype : post/get and you can fetch customer_name by using _GET or _POST there in another php file

Answer (score 0):

create separate php file as customer.php and write following code

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$customer_data = json_decode($content, true);
$customer_name  = $customer_data['customer_name'];

//using mysql query fetch all data of particular customer
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM partys WHERE party_name=$customer_name");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo json_encode($result);
```

after getting this alert json response in ajax call. This will give customer data.

and modify your ajax call as

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // On change of the dropdown do the ajax
    $("#client").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
                // Change the link to the file you are using
                url: 'customer.php',
                type: 'post',
                // This just sends the value of the dropdown
                 data: {customer_name : party_name},
                 dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    // Parse the jSON that is returned
                    // Using conditions here would probably apply
                    // incase nothing is returned
                    var response    =   JSON.parse(response);
                    // These are the inputs that will populate
                    $("#customer_address").val(response.customer_address);
                    $("#customer_phone").val(response.customer_phone);
                    $("#gstin").val(response.gstin);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: var response    =   JSON.parse(response);
                        // These are the inputs that will populate
                        $("#customer_address").val(response.customer_address);
                        $("#customer_phone").val(response.customer_phone);
                        $("#gstin").val(response.gstin);

Comment: can you show your create.php code?  how you are going to parse json data in create.php? Because when we are using json datatype in ajax, in php there is another method to get input from ajax.

Comment: create.php is the same file in which all this code is written

Comment: have you echo $customer_name = isset($_POST['customer_name']); then this will not work because you are using json datatype in ajax. instead of this method please try this code ::  $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$customer_name = json_decode($content, true); $customer_name will store your customer name which is send from ajax call.

Comment: I am completely new in ajax i am not understanding what you mean to say